# Use button and radio to submit form,but always the same value?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h1> It is a minion with one eye or two eyes</h1>

<div id="aside">
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
  </canvas>
<script>
   var bodyStyle = document.body.style; 
   bodyStyle.mozUserSelect = 'none'; 
   bodyStyle.webkitUserSelect = 'none'; 


   var img = new Image(); 
   var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); 
       canvas.style.backgroundColor='transparent'; 
       canvas.style.position = 'absolute'; 
   var imgs = ['p_2.jpg','p_3.jpg','p_4.jpg','p_5.jpg','p_6.jpg','p_7.jpg','p_8.jpg','p_9.jpg','p_10.jpg','p_12.jpg'
       ,'p_12.jpg','p_13.jpg','p_14.jpg','p_15.jpg','p_16.jpg','p_17.jpg','p_18.jpg','p_19.jpg','p_20.jpg','p_21.jpg','p_22.jpg',
       'p_23.jpg','p_24.jpg','p_25.jpg','p_26.jpg']; 
   var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*24); 
   var  effort=0;

   img.src = imgs[num]; 

   img.addEventListener('load', function(e) { 
          var ctx; 
        // var w = img.width, 
        //     h = img.height; 
          var w=600;
              h=500;
          var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft, 
              offsetY = canvas.offsetTop; 
          var mousedown = false; 

        function layer(ctx) { 
               ctx.fillStyle = 'gray'; 
               ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
               } 

        function eventDown(e){ 
               e.preventDefault(); 
               mousedown=true; 
               } 
        function eventUp(e){ 
               e.preventDefault(); 
               mousedown=false; 
               var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data;
               for(var i=0,j=0;i< data.length;i+=4){
                  if(data[i] && data[i+1] && data[i+2] && data[i+3]){
                  j++;
                  }
                effort=1-j/(w*h);
               }
              if(j<=w*h*0.2){
                  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
                  alert('ok');
                }

               }           

        function eventMove(e){ 
              e.preventDefault(); 
              if(mousedown) { 
                if(e.changedTouches){ 
                  e=e.changedTouches[e.changedTouches.length-1]; 
                } 
               var x = (e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft || e.pageX) - offsetX || 0, 
                   y = (e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop || e.pageY) - offsetY || 0; 
             with(ctx) { 
                 beginPath() 
             //arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);//绘制圆点 
                 rect(x,y,50,50);
                 fill(); 
            } 
          } 
        } 

        canvas.width=w; 
        canvas.height=h; 
        canvas.style.backgroundImage='url('+img.src+')'; 
        ctx=canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        ctx.fillStyle='transparent'; 
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        layer(ctx); 

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'; 

        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', eventDown); 
        canvas.addEventListener('touchend', eventUp); 
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', eventMove); 
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', eventDown); 
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', eventUp); 
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);  
    }); 

    </script>     



  </div> 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                      alert("already submit");
                      var taskid=num;
                      var name=$("#name").val();
                      var guessnum=$("#guessnum").val();

                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"GameMysql.php",
                          data:"name="+name+"&taskid="+taskid+"&guessnum="+guessnum+"&effort="+effort,

                         success:function(data){
                             $("#article").html(data);

                          }

                      });

                });
           });
    </script>
     <div id="article" >
      <form>
           name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
           </br>

         <!--  guessNum: <input type="number" name="guessnum" id="guessnum">   -->
          Select your guessNum: <br/ >
        <input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="1" id="guessnum" />   1
          </br >
         <input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="2" id="guessnum" />   2
          </br >
         <input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="3" id="guessnum" />   3
         </br >
         <input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="4" id="guessnum" />   4
        <br /> 
        <input type="button" value="Send Guess" id="submit">

   <!--  <input type="submit" value="Continue the Game" action="http://localhost.game5.php"> --> 
</form>
```

1 I use button and radio to submit the form, and the ajax read the guessNum data by id(#guessnum), but it always receives 1 no matter what the client submit, do not know why?

2 if I want to add a url link inside the success function of the ajax, how can i do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s should be unique, but you're using `guessnum` for 4 elements.  You can remove the `id`s and select on the name instead:

```
$("input[name=guessnum]").val();
```

However, that won't give you the correct answer, because it will always give you the value of the *first* input with that name – regardless of it's being selected or not.

Do this instead:

```
$("input[name=guessnum]:checked").val();
```

**Example:**

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  alert($("input[name=guessnum]:checked").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="1" id="guessnum" /> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="2" id="guessnum" /> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="3" id="guessnum" /> 3 <br>
<input type="radio" name="guessnum" value="4" id="guessnum" /> 4
<br>
<button id="b1">Show value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using same `id` guessnum for multiple elements which should not be done. And to get value of selected radio button :

```
$('input[name="genderS"]:checked').val();
```